# Abstract class properites does not work in typescript

Tags: typescript, getter-setter

I have this abstract class:

```
export abstract class Builder {
  static data: MyClass = {};

  get data(): MyClass {
    return Builder.data;
  }
  set data(value: MyClass) {
    Builder.data = value;
  }

  static member1() {}
  static member2() {}
  ...
}
```

I consume this class like so:

`Builder.data = {...}` however, it seems that getter and seetter does not make any effect.

In that case `Builder.data` referencing the static member.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Comment: `get` and `set` affect *instances*, not the static properties. So, with this code `new Builder().data = /* ... */` should be changing the static value. I've not tried it yet but that's what your code currently expresses.

Comment: @VLAZ Is there any way to emulate that within an abstract class?

Comment: Why do you need a getter and setter here? Or an abstract class? Or a static property to change? The combination of these is a bit strange. Normally, if you have a static property, you'd rarely change it. If you have a getter and setter, it won't be for a static property, either. I'm not sure what the end goal here is but I think re-designing this is the first step.